# MQTT streaming QoS control

Tags: streaming, real-time, mqtt, real-time-data, rtcp

Probably relating to the SO question [MQTT for realtime data streaming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39066691/mqtt-for-realtime-data-streaming), how would the realtime multimedia quality be achieved with MQTT?

This is different from the MQTT defined QoS 0, 1, or 2. In realtime streaming with RTP and RTCP, [these extra functionalities are explicitly supported](https://www.slideshare.net/vijendersingh1989/rtp-rtcp):

- Sequencing
- Time-stamping and buffering
- Rate control
- Quality feedback

Though the referenced [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39066691/mqtt-for-realtime-data-streaming) mentions VoIP are implemented on MQTT, how would the above factors be considered, or just ignored at all?

Edit: As @hardillb mentions below in the answer the "considerations would have to be implemented by application", what protocol the application should follow? Is RTP/RTCP over MQTT a good solution here?

Answer (score 1):

While in the previous answer I said VoIP had been implemented, I didn't say how robust it was.

As can be seen from other answers ([Is message order preserved?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30955110/is-message-order-preserved)) message order can be influenced by QOS.

All other considerations would have to be implemented by application using MQTT as it's transport.

Comment: Thanks for the quick and sensible response. Do you imply something like RTP or RTCP on top of MQTT?

Comment: I'm not implying anything